# HTML5 : Using a static thumbnail/poster with video tag when while pre-loading metadata

Tags: html, thumbnails, preload

When we use an HTML video tag with `preload = "metadata"`, it automatically loads the thumbnail whether or not the poster attribute is present. I wish to make sure that the poster attribute value remains the permanent thumbnail without using `preload = "none"`.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is weird. In the [MDN document and example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#examples), the poster remains despite metadata (length) loaded. And the instruction explicitly stat that behavior: Until the video starts playing, the image provided in the poster attribute is displayed in its place.

Comment: Yes, I figured my issue was because I was loading the src video from a particular timestamp i.e. ending with &t=600. That somehow messed it up.

Comment: If that's the case, maybe you need to use a cover element (i.e. `div`) and javascript to toggle it.